# Why do we need ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK and what is the purpose of this table and why does ACTIVITI create it?

Tags: java, mysql, database, activiti, bpmn

mysql> DESCRIBE ACT_RU_IDENTITYLINK;

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID_           | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| REV_          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| GROUP_ID_     | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| TYPE_         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| USER_ID_      | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| TASK_ID_      | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| PROC_INST_ID_ | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| PROC_DEF_ID_  | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Please explain what gets stored in the table and why do we need this if we already have ACT_ID_MANAGEMENT??

Comment: You should ask the developers of activiti...

Answer (score 3):

An Identity Link is used to associate a task with a certain identity. For example, a user or a group can be an assignee for a task. For this purpose, it has a type, userId, groupId and taskId. ProcessDefinitionId and ProcessInstanceId are just to link to the definition and executing instance.